# Roslyn CTP damaged my Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed the Roslyn CTP, and it worked beatifully for the most part. Then it was time to part with Roslyn, because some features I use aren't implemented yet, and Roslyn replaced the standard compiler. It may be too late for me, but for the afterworld there's still hope:

Is there a way to repair Visual Studio 2010 so it functions like before installing the Roslyn CTP?

**Udate:** I tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2010 Professional, to no avail. Now I'm investigating the error log, and it says:

> CreateInstance failed for package
>   [Roslyn.VisualStudio.VisualBasic.LanguageService.VisualBasicPackage,
>   Roslyn.VisualStudio.VisualBasic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]

Is there a setting I can change so Visual Studio uses the old compiler again?

**Update 2:** There would have been an on/off button in the settings.

**Update 3:** The on/off button doesn't show. Instead the settings pages for Roslyn stay blank.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The quickest solution would just to repair your installation of Visual Studio using the installer.

Comment: Tried that first, didn't work.